# How to scale image edges to fill background in android?

Tags: android, scaling, android-imageview

I have a logo image with a background gradient. However, this image doesn't fill the screen its surrounded by black bars, making it look bad. Is there anyway in android I can specify to scale the edges of the image (i.e. the last pixel on each side) and stretch that color out until it fills the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you could use a 9-Patch image to scale the edges of your background image.  Take a look at the following page and see if that will help you out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: I just ended up centering the images and I'm waiting on the client to provide better graphics if its a problem for them. Accepted this as a possible solution.